# Javascript function parameters issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass parameters to a function. I have:

```
function test(var1, var2, var3, var4, callBack, Scroll, punc, var5){
    codes....
}
```

When I call the function:

```
test('a','b','c','d','e');
```

I want `'e'` to be `var 5` instead of `callback` parameter.  Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: If you call `test()` with those arguments, what do you want the values stored in `callBack`, `Scroll`, and `punc` to be?  They can't come from nowhere.

Comment: What are you looking to change here? Are you looking to modify the function `test` so that you can call it in the way you describe? Or are you looking to modify the call to `test` so that it matches what the function expects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`test('a','b','c','d',null,null,null,'e');`

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your function but supposing it accepts to lack a callback you could do this :

```
test('a','b','c','d', undefined, undefined, undefined, 'e');
```

If it really needs a callback, do this :

```
test('a','b','c','d',function(){}, undefined, undefined, 'e');
```